# Numeric type as DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

How to register custom property which based on numeric type?

```
public class NumberBox : TextBox
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FormatProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FormatValue", typeof(Type), typeof(NumberBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(default(Double)));
        public Type FormatValue
        {
            get
            {
                return (Type)GetValue(FormatProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(FormatProperty, value);
            }
        }
   }
```

XAML

```
<nb:NumberBox FormatValue="{System:Int32}"/>
```

I am sure, that is not perfect, but I really don't know how it make workable.

UPDATE:

Basically, me need to have a way to set the type of my number box. For example, if I need to use `Double` NumberBox I just set `FormatValue="Double"`

Comment: Why are you using a type as a property? Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: Perhaps:) But I don't know

Comment: why don't you use a masked text box?

Comment: `default(Double)` returns `0` as a double. You want the `Type` object as your default property value -- `typeof(Double)`.

Comment: I agree with @DanielA.White. What problem are you really trying to solve? Once you set that FormatValue dependency property, what do you plan to do with it? It is possible that if we know the end result, there may be an entirely better solution that may not even involve an extra dependency property.

Comment: @Kess - See the accepted answer, it works and it what I wanted to did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** issue is *default metadata provided in last parameter of DP identifier is incorrect*.

Instead of

`new UIPropertyMetadata(default(Double))`,

it should be

`new UIPropertyMetadata(typeof(Double))`

**Second** issue in XAML. Use **`x:Type`** to pass type.

```
<nb:NumberBox xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
              FormatValue="{x:Type sys:Int32}"/>
```

Comment: My code doesn't work at all, I just tried to resolve this issue

Comment: "[XAML 2009 adds support for these primitives: x:Object, x:Boolean, x:Char, x:String, x:Decimal, x:Single, x:Double, x:Int16, x:Int32, x:Int64, x:TimeSpan, x:Uri, x:Byte, and x:Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)"

Comment: @clcto - Yeah these primitives are available post WPF 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

From here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, the types are `x:Int32`, `x:Double`, ...

So you want to use:

```
 <nb:NumberBox FormatValue="{x:Type x:Int32}"/>
```

In the general sense, you would have to include the namespace in the XAML:

```
 <Window ...
         xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:MyNamepsace;assembly=MyAssembly"
         >

     <nb:NumberBox FormatValue="{x:Type ns:MyType}"/>
 </Window>
```